# Full screen shader causes performance hit

Tags: c++, shaders, glsl, hlsl, allegro

I basically want to have a shader run that can do something like toon shading, or grayscale the whole screen, or radial lighting.

To do this, I create a new bitmap each time the display resizes that is the size of the screen. I then use this as my drawing buffer.

I realized this creates quite a performance hit. Especially on my laptop. Is there a way to do something like this without such a performance hit?

The framework I'm using is Allegro5. This is my current implementation:

```
void GraphicsContext::flipDisplay()
{
    if(!m_backBuffer)
    {
        al_flip_display();
    }
    else
    {   

        setTargetToBackbuffer();
        if(m_shader)
        {
            m_shader->use();
            m_shader->setSampler(m_backBuffer,"tex");
        }
        drawSprite(m_backBuffer,0,0,0);
        if(m_shader)
        {
            m_shader->stop();
        }

        al_flip_display();
        clear();
        setTargetToBuffer();

    }

}
```

This way all drawing gets drawn to my bitmap, then that bitmap is blitted to the backbuffer.

I tried using single buffering display but it did not help.

Any advice for fullscreen effects?
I have a game I play on my laptop that uses fullscreen film grain and it does not lag. I wonder what they do.

I know that the default shader I set gets ran through every bitmap, but I do not think I can do lighting effects this way since I cannot know which pixel on the screen I'm on.

Comment: Why not draw directly to screen or to a frame buffer? Drawing to a bitmap is causing the slowdown.

Comment: I cannot draw directly to screen because for the effect to work I need the final image to go through the shader. I'm using a library called Allegro5 and I'm not sure how to create / use a frame buffer.

Comment: If I read this correctly it looks like Allegro5 can use FBO's http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Hardware_Portability but I've never used Allegro5 so I wouldn't know where to start looking. Someone else will know. I've edited your question to include this info (someone might need to approve the edit before people can see it)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to single buffer is fine, but it should not be reallocated every time the display size changes. Make a buffer the max texture size or sufficiently large enough to cover all possible screen sizes. Then make a sub bitmap of the large buffer texture that you use for drawing. This can then be drawn to screen using your shader.

FYI, allegro 5 can set / tell you what type of display mechanism is in use, whether it is double buffer, page flipping, or triple buffer behind the scenes.